# How to hide image of external java sciprt code on wordpress site

Tags: javascript

I need a solution to hide a image of external javascript.
I have a website. I am using a free tracker service to track my visitor. So, the tracker give me a code which I placed in footer of my site. But the script create a little image icon. Which is clickable. So, anyone can see my site data.
So, I want to use the tracker code, but hide the image. Which make sure only I'm able to view all of my site data. The javascript code is encrypted or much complex. So, I can't solve my problem. I google for similar questions. But answer is not specific. As, I am a beginner, I need details instruction.

I added the source code. here "jbahe" is my username. My site is https://jagobahe.com

Thanks in advance.

```
<script src="//t1.extreme-dm.com/f.js" id="eXF-jbahe-0" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the image with CSS

```
#eXTReMe-Free-jbahe {
    display:none;
}
```

Or if you must use JS

```
document.getElementById('eXTReMe-Free-jbahe').style.display = 'none'
```

Comment: where to add these code in wordpress? Please don't mind. I'm beginner. So, I need more information.

Comment: You can add this as a text node anywhere on the page `<script>document.getElementById('eXTReMe-Free-jbahe').style.display = 'none'</script>`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added your code to my footer beside the main script code. But its not hiding the image. Should I delete the original code?
Please remember. I need to use the tracing code. I just want to hide the image as anyone can't see my site data.

Comment: this code is work. It hides the image. But js is not working. It not tracking.
` #eXTReMe-Free-jbahe {
    display:none;
}`